# Best practices for using NSwag 'AspNetCoreToSwaggerGenerator'

Tags: swagger, nswag

I've been using [NSwag](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag) for a while to generate an Angular TS client to my WebAPI and I love it.

I'm finally moving away from NSwagStudio to using MSBuild targets to automatically generate my json specification.

I see that there is a new way to generate specs called `AspNetCoreToSwaggerGenerator`, which uses the [ASP.NET Core API Explorer](https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-the-apiexplorer-in-asp-net-core/) service.

The [docs](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/AspNetCoreToSwaggerGenerator) specify:

> This generator uses the [ASP.NET Core API Explorer](https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-the-apiexplorer-in-asp-net-core/) service to generate specs and will eventually supersede the reflection based generator [WebApiToSwaggerGenerator](https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/WebApiToSwaggerGenerator). It is recommended to use this generator for new projects and also start migrating existing projects.

So I thought great I'll use that. However I suddenly got some errors about missing paths, that turned out to be from my startup.cs file. I thought that was weird until i realized that it was actually spinning up an instance of my Startup class and running the code - makes sense if it's using the API Explorer.

However this strikes me as not only potentially very dangerous (if I did some weird coding in the Startup), but also potentially slower if it's running through a lot of startup code.

I switched to using the older `WebApiToSwaggerGenerator` like this :

```
  <Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Reference)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core21) webapi2swagger /assembly:$(OutDir)RR.API.DLL /output:rrapi.json" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutDir)References" />
  </Target>
```

This generates me a `rrapi.json` file that I can then run in my Angular build to actually create the client. It seems to be quite fast and works well.

So I'm left wonder what are the best practices, and benefits of the newer `AspNetCoreToSwaggerGenerator`. Specifically :

- How to prevent unnecessary code from running from my Startup.cs file
- What are the actual benefits? Is this to enable more advanced metadata via the API Explorer service - or some future proofing for Swagger 3?
- What are the benchmarks of using either for a typical project.

I basically want a static .json file generated everytime I build my WebAPI client. I don't right now see any reason not to use the older generator.

---

Update: this is what I ended up using (aspnetcore2swagger). I don't remember the exact details of everything going on here, but this has been working well. It creates an intermediate rr.api.json file (I have all my API stuff in RR.API project).

```
 <!-- https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/1159#issuecomment-363886104 -->
 <Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build">

   <Copy SourceFiles="@(ReferencePath)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)References" />
   <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core31) aspnetcore2swagger  /documentName:a /assembly:$(ProjectDir)bin\$(Configuration)\netcoreapp3.1\RR.API.dll /output:$(SpaRoot_APIRoot)rr.api.json" />

   <!-- SAVE https://localhost:5001/swagger/a/swagger.json -->
   <!-- TO http://localhost:54712/src/app/shared/api/rr.api.json -->
   <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Core31) run $(SpaRoot_APIRoot)rr.api.nswag /variables:SpaRoot_APIRoot=$(SpaRoot_APIRoot)" />
   <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutDir)References" />

</Target>
```

I have `SpaRoot_APIRoot` defined as:

```
<SpaRoot_APIRoot>..\MyAngularProject\src\app\shared\api\</SpaRoot_APIRoot>
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve that issue? I am having the same issue myself at the moment.

Comment: @MaTTo Give me a minute and I'll update it. Looks like I'm using aspnetcore2swagger